# xPath for a specific line of text when the node contains multiple lines of text

Tags: html, css, xpath

I have an html that looks like this:

```html
<div class='textContainer'>
    <div class='textLabel'> </div>
    <div class='text'> 
    "First Line of text" 
    "Second Line of text" 
    "Third line of text" 
    </div>
</div>
```

I can easily create a locator to find the node that contains the text, but I need to run an assertion specifically on the first and third lines of text... So, I would need specific locators for those.
Like

- `//div[@class='text']/text[1]`
- `//div[@class='text']/text[3]`

Is that even possible to do?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible, yes. But extracting the lines of text is fiddly. I believe you can use substring-before() and substring-after() around new-line characters to extract each line.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with XPath 2 or 3, e.g. in the browser or Node.js with Saxon-JS 2 you have XPath 3.1 support:

```js
const lines = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`//div[@class = 'text']/tokenize(., '\n')[normalize-space()]!normalize-space()`, document, { xpathDefaultNamespace : 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' });

console.log(lines);
console.log(lines[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation/SaxonJS/SaxonJS2.rt.js"></script>

<div class='textContainer'>
    <div class='textLabel'> </div>
    <div class='text'> 
    "First Line of text" 
    "Second Line of text" 
    "Third line of text" 
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that in any version of XPath or the DOM the normalized tree has a single text node but in XPath 2 or later you can split or tokenize the string of a text node into sequences of strings and process each string in the sequence. The Saxon-JS 2 API to JavaScript nicely gives you that XPath 3.1 string sequence back as a string array in JavaScript.

In terms of the XPath 2 or 3 data model the path expression `//div[@class = 'text']/tokenize(., '\n')[normalize-space()]!normalize-space()` gives a sequence of string you can positionally index as usually in XPath with integer numbers so `let $lines := //div[@class = 'text']/tokenize(., '\n')[normalize-space()]!normalize-space() return $lines[2]` returns the second item/second string in the sequence of strings (of normalized text lines of the text node).